# List of non-empty tables in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I get MySQL to return all non-empty tables in a database? Much like "SHOW TABLES" but only those that are not empty.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

'information_schema' should be holding the relevant details. You can try

```
SELECT table_type,
       table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_rows >= 1;
```

to select from a selective database. You can also filter by `TABLE_SCHEMA`:

```
SELECT table_schema,
       table_type,
       table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_rows >= 1
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA=?
```

Comment: It's worth noting that for InnoDB it is not guaranteed to work 100% of the time.  `table_rows` in `information_schema` is just an estimation and might not reflect the real number of rows, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html

Comment: This didn't work for me at all, I've posted solution that did work below.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer never worked for me, *information_schema* *table_rows* have some very weird values.

This worked like a charm:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Rows > 0;
```

[Docs for SHOW TABLE STATUS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-table-status.html)

Answer (score 7):

Use database 'information_schema' and run

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_ROWS` > 0
```

this will give you all non-empty tables in the server for a certain database run

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_ROWS` > 0  AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'database_name'
```

Comment: are you sure it works? It does not for me. It says 'Unknown column `Table_Rows` in where clause. '

Comment: Do you use MySQL? Which version?

Comment: SELECT * FROM information_schema.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_ROWS` > 0 @YasenZhelev little correction

Comment: @Vipul Hadiya It already says that 'information_schema' database need to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query via phpMyAdmin:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM  `information_schema`.`TABLES` 
WHERE  `TABLE_ROWS` > 0
```

will return a list of non-empty tables

Comment: oops, change the "=" to > to find tables with rows.