# How can i verify that all my tables are empty with HQL/Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have a big functionnal test suite. Each test are independant.
But, from time to time, there is a problem and one of these tests leaks (exception happens before the data could be cleaned etc) and some of the subsequent tests could fail.

So the first thing i want to do in each of these test is check if the database is really empty. It would help to know that the breakage is due to a leak and not a regression.

I would like to know if i can do this with a single request, because I'd like to avoid doing and maintaining something like :

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("Select a From A a").list().isEmpty()
...
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("Select z From Z z").list().isEmpty()
```

I found this for mysql : [List of non-empty tables in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746201/list-of-non-empty-tables-in-mysql-database) but it is specific.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What I do is set my "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" to create in the hibernate.cfg.xml and in each test I reset my sessionfactory using

```
sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

This way the database is recreated for each test

Comment: that's an idea, but i fear it will take an awful lot of time to execute. If i don't find anything else, i'll test your solution.

Comment: @Maxime: Do not optimize prematurely

Comment: That's not my code, these are my tests. I run them at each build (surfire with mvn test) so i can't have them to take too long.

Comment: anyway, I use this solution too, and when my DB is just for testing, it is quite small, then this runs pretty fast... is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
session.createQuery("select 1 from table").setMaxSize(1).list().isEmpty()
```

Comment: the "select 1 from table" will fetch data from every table in my base ?

Comment: replace it by specific table name

Comment: i said in my question i didn't want to do a query by table, that's painful and not maintainable.