# Check the databases with no records using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to check more than 300 databases if they are not empty, and display names of database with no tables inside.

This is my code [EDIT] :

```
<?php

    $db = ['db_1', 'db_2', 'db_3', 'db_4'];

    foreach ($db as $db_name) {
        $conn = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", $db_name) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Conect error: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM " . $db_name . "";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($result == NULL) {
        foreach ($db as $db_name) {
            echo "Empty database:" . $db_name . "</br>";
        }
    } else {
        exit;
    }

    ?>
```

But the code returns all databases ,

Comment: Do you really mean "databases" or "tables"?

Comment: You haven't defined `$query`

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/foreach and http://php.net/mysql_query. In the grand scheme of things, you shouldn't be using the `mysql_*()` functions anyways. They're obsolete/deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: The sql for that is `select count(*) from table` and loop through the tables. But you're going to have to conquer the horrible mistakes in using the `mysql_` extension first. Since you don't know how to use this extension, go ahead and switch to PDO so you can learn to do db stuff in PHP right from the beginning.

Comment: A simple Google search for "check for empty tables mysql" will get you started.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746201/list-of-non-empty-tables-in-mysql-database would probably constitute as a duplicate question.

Comment: Following your array edit, use `foreach ($db as $dbName) {}` and use `$dbName` instead of `$db_name['database']`.

Comment: developerwjk - i wannt to check all database if they have any tables inside.

Code updated.

Comment: Now you're mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli` OOP.  Just switch to PDO already, as it will prevent you from accidentally dropping off that `i` or persisting in using old `mysql_` functions.

Comment: @user3378777 Your PHP version may not support square brackets for arrays, so try changing `$db = ['db_1', 'db_2', 'db_3', 'db_4'];` to `$db = array('db_1', 'db_2', 'db_3', 'db_4');`. I tested the answer below using both methods which worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

$db = ['db_1', 'db_2', 'db_3', 'db_4'];

$conn = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass") or die("Error connecting: " . mysqli_error($conn));

foreach ($db as $db_name) {

    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM " . $db_name;

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (!$result) {
        echo "Unable to get tables from:" . $db_name . "<br />";
    } else {
        if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0 )
            echo "Empty database:" . $db_name . "</br>";
        }
    }

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Sidenote:

If your PHP version does not support square brackets for arrays, try changing:

```
$db = ['db_1', 'db_2', 'db_3', 'db_4'];
```

to

```
$db = array('db_1', 'db_2', 'db_3', 'db_4');
```

Comment: Sadlz its not working. Got the error : Unable to get tables from:db_1..... and all databases.

Comment: I've updated it. Please let me know if you're still having issues.

Comment: @Danbopes There was an extra brace at the end which I removed in an edit and added a different array method.